# Access Database: Averages across two consecutive months

Tags: database, ms-access, join, average, period

I have a table in an access database with essentially two critical fields: "Period" (as YYYYMM, so e.g. 202111, 202112, 202201 and so on) and, further, a dollar amount as field "Volume Balance". The goal is now to calculate a simple average for every two consecutive months like the bottom table (exemplary numbers, unit is USD):

Input -->

| Period | Volume Balance |
| --- | --- |
| 202101 | 1 |
| 202102 | 2 |
| 202103 | 3 |

Desired Result -->

| Period | Average Volume Balance |
| --- | --- |
| 202102 | 1.5 ((Jan+Feb)/2) |
| 202103 | 2.5 ((Feb+Mar)/2) |

I have played around with the DAvg function but the consecutive period cut-offs are fatal for me. Thank you for any help!

Comment: OPTION 1) Use an iif to evaluate if period in (period OR period - 1 Month) then volume balance; else 0)/2  so volume balance will be populated twice 0 otherwise and then divide by 2...  OPTION 2) perform a self outer join on period and period -1 (using SQL).  then average. and group by the period on your main table.  You may need to convert your date to a "Date" object to do the date math and then render back to formatted text of YYYYMM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a self join:

```
SELECT t1.Period, 
       (t1.[Volume Balance] + t2.[Volume Balance]) / 2 AS [Average Volume Balance]
FROM tablename AS t1 INNER JOIN tablename AS t2
ON VAL(t1.Period) = VAL(t2.Period) + 1;
```

If the data type of `Period` is a numeric type then change the ON clause to just:

```
ON t1.Period = t2.Period + 1;
```

Comment: Hi forpas, this worked perfectly! Thank you for the quick help.

Comment: Just one quick follow-up question. Indeed, I have a slightly more complex table where I have two other inputs "ID number" and "Instrument", both short texts. Accordingly, my table has the same period multiple times with different amounts per IDs and Instruments. When I run the above, I think access is computing a Cartesian product as the number of records I get is very large. I tried grouping by ID and instrument, but this is only giving me errors. Any guidance as to how to group this by ID and instrument?

Comment: @DVEF This query works only if Period is unique, just like your sample data. If Period is not unique the rows are joined multiple times. Since this is a new requirement you should ask a new question, with sample data where you will clarify your expected results.

Comment: Understood, I will make it a new question - thanks!